# How to set a default return value for an ON_CALL to a const method for gmock?

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have two different methods:

```
MOCK_METHOD(const std::shared_ptr< const A >&, func, (), (const));
MOCK_METHOD(const std::shared_ptr< A >&, func, ());
```

And i set a ON_CALL action like this:

```
std::shared_ptr< A > value = std::make_shared< A >();
ON_CALL(*ptr, func()).WillByDefault(ReturnRef(value));
```

If I run the test the `const` method is invoked but gmock claims that no default action is set.
If I change the code to

```
std::shared_ptr< const A > value = std::make_shared< const A >();
ON_CALL(*ptr, func()).WillByDefault(ReturnRef(value));
```

It won't work. Instead I get an compile error C2440 (`'return': cannot convert from 'T' to 'const std::shared_ptr< A >&'`)

Comment: `ON_CALL(Const(*ptr), func()).`

Answer (score 3):

The comment by @Piotr Skotnicki was a good hint to look at the correct code block in the cookbook:

```
using ::testing::ReturnRef;

class MockFoo : public Foo {

  MOCK_METHOD(Bar&, GetBar, (), (override));
  MOCK_METHOD(const Bar&, GetBar, (), (const, override));
};


  MockFoo foo;
  Bar bar1, bar2;
  EXPECT_CALL(foo, GetBar())         // The non-const GetBar().
      .WillOnce(ReturnRef(bar1));
  EXPECT_CALL(Const(foo), GetBar())  // The const GetBar().
      .WillOnce(ReturnRef(bar2));
```